# EE1 to EE2 upgrade error SELECT field_id FROM exp_weblog_fields WHERE field_type = 'date'

Tags: ee1, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

getting this error during an EE1 - EE2 upgrade:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'dbname_ee.exp_weblog_fields' doesn't exist

SELECT field_id FROM exp_weblog_fields WHERE field_type = 'date'

Filename: updates/ud_200.php

Line Number: 1930
```

NEW ERROR::

```
{"error":"
Error Number: 1064<\/p>\n\n

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`wm_name` varchar(80),\n\t`wm_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'text',\n\t`wm_image_path` v' at line 3<\/p>\n\n

ALTER TABLE `exp_member_groups` ADD \n\t`wm_id` int(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,\n\t`wm_name` varchar(80),\n\t`wm_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'text',\n\t`wm_image_path` varchar(100),\n\t`wm_test_image_path` varchar(100),\n\t`wm_use_font` char(1) DEFAULT 'y',\n\t`wm_font` varchar(30),\n\t`wm_font_size` int(3) UNSIGNED,\n\t`wm_text` varchar(100),\n\t`wm_vrt_alignment` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'top',\n\t`wm_hor_alignment` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'left',\n\t`wm_padding` int(3) UNSIGNED,\n\t`wm_opacity` int(3) UNSIGNED,\n\t`wm_x_offset` int(4) UNSIGNED,\n\t`wm_y_offset` int(4) UNSIGNED,\n\t`wm_x_transp` int(4),\n\t`wm_y_transp` int(4),\n\t`wm_font_color` varchar(7),\n\t`wm_use_drop_shadow` char(1) DEFAULT 'y',\n\t`wm_shadow_distance` int(3) UNSIGNED,\n\t`wm_shadow_color` varchar(7),\n\t`id` int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,\n\t`upload_location_id` int(4) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',\n\t`title` varchar(255),\n\t`short_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',\n\t`resize_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',\n\t`width` int(10) DEFAULT '0',\n\t`height` int(10) DEFAULT '0',\n\t`watermark_id` int(4) UNSIGNED,\n\t`file_id` int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,\n\t`cat_id` int(10) UNSIGNED,\n\t`sort` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',\n\t`is_cover` char(1) DEFAULT 'n',\n\t`site_id` int(4) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '1',\n\t`rel_path` varchar(255),\n\t`status` char(1) DEFAULT 'o',\n\t`mime_type` varchar(255),\n\t`file_name` varchar(255),\n\t`file_size` int(10) DEFAULT '0',\n\t`field_1` text,\n\t`field_1_fmt` tinytext,\n\t`field_2` text,\n\t`field_2_fmt` tinytext,\n\t`field_3` text,\n\t`field_3_fmt` tinytext,\n\t`field_4` text,\n\t`field_4_fmt` tinytext,\n\t`field_5` text,\n\t`field_5_fmt` tinytext,\n\t`field_6` text,\n\t`field_6_fmt` tinytext,\n\t`metadata` mediumtext NULL,\n\t`uploaded_by_member_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',\n\t`upload_date` int(10),\n\t`modified_by_member_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',\n\t`modified_date` int(10),\n\t`file_hw_original` varchar(20),\n\t`can_admin_upload_prefs` CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'n' NOT NULL AFTER `can_admin_channels`<\/p>\n\n

Filename: \/home\/user\/admin\/expressionengine\/libraries\/Smartforge.php<\/p>\n\n

Line Number: 122<\/p>"}
```

this is line 122:

```
if (ee()->dbforge->add_column($table, array($k => $field[$k]), $after_field))
```

Comment: restored teh DB and started again, now getting the new error above

Answer (score 1):

ended up going back to an old server backup to restore the old site.  WIll try again from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try restoring the original directory for the field types. Not sure if this idea is transferable, but we had an issue upgrading from 2.55 to 2.7 where our "Relationship" channel fields broke.

Uploading the old `rel` folder into the `fieldtypes` folder then allowed us to change those fields in the control panel into the new "Relationships" field type.